# Trigger twitter typeahead on placeholder attribute in input field

Tags: javascript, html, autosuggest, twitter-typeahead

I have a input field on which we have added a search behavior using typeahead.

The requirement is to set a placeholder in input field and trigger the typeahead results/search based on that placeholder value

Example :

In input field i set a placeholder `Cricket`...so search results come with cricket and its following suggestions based on algo we keep.

If user wants to select anything out of that, he will click from presented results, else will start typing whatever he wants and selects based on results.

**So basically triggering twitter typeahead on placeholder**, rest its default behavior will take care of.

**Sample Code :**

```
$("#input-id").attr("placeholder","cricket").eq(0).trigger("input");
```

**What i want to achieve doing this :**

- I want to prefill the input field by most accurate suggestion based on user's preference. I have two options
- If i do it via value, then i am achieving this. But if user does not want to use my suggestions, they need to clear the input first before typing their intention
- If above is possible via placeholder, it would make a best user experience. As if they like my hint, they will select the suggestion move ahead, else straight away start typing and get results.

Comment: Could you instead use actual input but style with a class to look like a placholder? Then you'd just need to toggle that class on and off when necessary.

Comment: Yes i am already doing that but that creates difficulty for my user..Example : i just want to prefill the field with most accurate suggestion for a user as i mentioned for user..If it would be a value, then user need to remove or clear that first if they need to add something totally different...in case of placeholder they could have just started typing

Comment: Are you using HTML5? Have you considered getting the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: I am trying to use placeholder attribute, but search is not getting triggered on that. This is the issue.

Comment: What code you are trying to set placeholder?

Comment: I am setting the placeholder on the input using jquery : $("#input-id").attr("placeholder","cricket")